# Blueman tray crashes on Ubuntu Studio 20.04 session start

Tags: 20.04, blueman

When starting a session, an "Ubuntu 20.04 internal error" dialogue pops up. The details reveal a blueman-tray crash due to the file /home/username/.cache/blueman.tray-1000 not being found. The file actually exists, isn't empty and seems to have correct permissions. Any idea how to fix this?

Extended details:

> Executable Path: /usr/bin/blueman-tray
> Package: blueman 2.1.2-1
> Problem Type: Crash
> Title: blueman-tray crashed with FileNotFoundError in check_single_instance(): [Errno 2] File or directory doesn't exist: '/home/username/.cache/blueman-tray-1000'

Comment: Related bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/+bug/1871336

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem constantly in Mate on my Raspberry Pi 4. Until the bug is fixed the graphical manager is more trouble than it's worth and I can always use bluetoothctl in the terminal. So my solution was to execute 'sudo apt-get remove blueman' and delete the files in /var/crash. They shouldn't grow back, and the first reboot was quicker than ever before.

Comment: Thank you. I used your solution, changing "remove" for "purge". In my case, Bluetooth is irrelevant on my desktop, so I don't mind completely getting rid of this package.

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work for me. I found it in a French Ubuntu Forum linking to a solution from Norbert-X (Kudos):

[Blueman-tray crash](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445880&s=68d937678af834fce31a7f7164765bd0&p=13982395#post13982395%3C/a%3E)

Basically, it is this sequence of commands in a terminal and then reboots. The error message then disappeared.

```
ls -ald ~/.cache
ls -al ~/.cache/blueman-* 
killall blueman-tray
rm  ~/.cache/blueman-* 
blueman-tray
```